# How can i get this "askopenfilename" result without any loop or doubled open?

Tags: python, button, tkinter

How can I get `fname` without any loop? When I write `a=loadfile()` the window opens 2 times. How can I fix this?

```
def loadfile():
    fname = askopenfilename(filetypes=(("Image files(jpg,jpeg,tif,tiff,bmp,png", ("*.jpg","*.jpeg","*.tif","*.tiff","*.png","*.bmp")),
                                       ("All files", "*.*")))

    return fname


buton=Button(frame1,text="File",fg="red",command=loadfile)
buton.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky=W)

label2= Label(frame1,width=58)
label2.grid(row=0,column=2,sticky=E)

a=fname


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please try to create a complete example using [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: My guess of your code works as expected. Note that you can't really return values from methods you use as button callbacks, they should be instead _modifying_ values.

Comment: There's nowhere in your code that you do `a=loadfile()`, so your code and your description do not seem to be related.

Comment: `return fname` is useless in function executed by `Button`. Load file and diplay it inside function `loadfile`.